# jquery hover fade on menu fade background issues

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover

first off am using wordpress but this is just the platform am using.
down to the issue am having with hit states..

main menu with sub nav, when rollover a menu item there is a separate div which fades in the background and rollout fades out

but there is a few bugs am having with the hit states and the fading
if you rolover to quickly then the fade is not complete and if over a sub nav link it fades the background div out...

this is js am using to

```
$("#main-navigation li, #menu-footer-nav li").hover(
  function () {
    $(".nav-overlay-bottom").stop(true).fadeIn('slow');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(".nav-overlay-bottom").stop(true).fadeOut('slow');
  }
);
```

i should also mention that on one menu it fades in a different bg div than the rest...

```
$("#menu-item-1260").hover( function () {
    $(".nav-overlay").stop(true).fadeIn('slow');
        //$("#header").addClass("border-hover-top");
  }, 
  function () {
    $(".nav-overlay").stop(true).fadeOut('slow');
        //$("#header").removeClass("border-hover-top");

  }
);
```

my js is not great so am sure there is a better way to write this ?

Comment: Try `.stop(true, true)` to force the animation to complete instantly, or don't use `.stop()` at all to let the animations queue up.

Comment: tried `.stop(true, true)`but this causes a flicking when rolling over other nav items and taking off the stop makes each item u rollover play even after you moved off

Comment: You might want to create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the problem, otherwise it's hard for us to actually visualise the problem you're having.